# Implementing PHP array_column in Rust

Tags: rust, array-column

I'm in the process of learning `Rust`, but I could not find an answer to this question.

In PHP, there's the `array_column` method and it works this way:

given an array of arrays (this would be a a Vector of vectors in Rust):

```
$records = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]
];
```

if I want to get an array containing all the first elements (a "column") of the inner arrays I can do:

```
$column = array_column($records, 0);
```

This way, for example, I get `[1,1,1,1]`. If I change that 0 with 1, I get `[2,2,2,2]` and so on.

Since there's no `array_column` equivalent in Rust (that is: I could not find it), what could be the best way to implement a similar behavior with a vector of vectors?

Comment: I assume PHP doesn't do any magic with memory, because subarrays are probably placed in differents parts of memory. So just make a new vector with capacity of `records`'s size, then iterate each element in outer vector, and add in your result a `subvector[k]` element. You should also check if every `subvector` has size greater than k

Comment: @AlexLarionov: thanks for your comment! Basically, your solution is my solution but I thought I was missing something big when I found you can do something like this: `let zipped: Vec<_> = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).collect();` (this only works with 2 vectors and it's not enough for me). I don't know what PHP does at a low level, but the implementation of array_column is really fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to play with iterators, as you tried in the comments.

This version works with any clonable values (numbers included). We iterate over subvectors, and for each we call a `get` method, which either yields an element of the vector `Some(&e)` or `None` if we ask out of bounds.

`and_then` then accepts a value from `get`, and if it was `None`, then `None` is returned, otherwise, if it's `Some(&e)` then `Some(e.clone())` is returned, i.e. we clone the value (because we only have the reference to the value from `get`, we can't store it, we have to copy the value).

`collect` then works with `Iter<Option<T>>`, and it conveniently turns it in `Option<Vec<T>>`, i.e. it returns `None` if some `None`s were in the iterator (which means some arrays didn't have big enough size), or returns `Some(Vec<T>)`, if everything is fine.

```
fn main() {
    let array = vec![
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
        vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
    ];
    let ac = array_column(&array, 0);
    println!("{:?}", ac); // Some([1, 1, 1, 1])

    let ac = array_column(&array, 3);
    println!("{:?}", ac); // Some([4, 4, 4, 4])

    let ac = array_column(&array, 4); // None
    println!("{:?}", ac);
}

fn array_column<T: Clone>(array: &Vec<Vec<T>>, column: usize) -> Option<Vec<T>> {
    array.iter()
        .map( |subvec| subvec.get(column).and_then(|e| Some(e.clone())) )
        .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Alex version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61661142/1695172) is good, but you can generalize it using references too, so there will be no need for the item to be `Clone`:

```rust
fn array_column<'a, T>(array: &'a Vec<Vec<T>>, column: usize) -> Option<Vec<&'a T>> {
    array.iter()
        .map( |subvec| subvec.get(column) )
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10af2ed30a8d5e5709adb48924203062)

Comment: Exactly, but as a side note, you cannot drop the source array while a result of the function exists somewhere. Might be inconvenient to use then

Comment: @AlexLarionov, well, you have the compiler check that for you so you can always explicitly clone later when needed also.